# What does putting a string in single quotes mean in bash?

Tags: bash

```
VALUE1=123
VALUE2=456
S_ID=123456789
G_ID=34634
```

`/opt/customtools/custom_cmd -a -g $G_ID -m custom -c '=value9 $S_ID $VALUE1 $VALUE2'`

Never worked with bash scripting before and I'm looking through some code now and I've spotted this, and for some reason I can't find anywhere on the internet that describes what the end of this line does (the '=value9...part). Concatenate? Add? Please advise.

Comment: None of the above is valid bash.

Comment: or, rather, none of it does anything useful. `VALUE1 = 123`, for instance, *doesn't* assign `123` to `VALUE1`; rather, it runs a command named `VALUE1` with the first argument `=` and the second argument `123`

Comment: Assignments in `bash` can't have spaces around the `=`.

Comment: so, clearly the file you're looking at isn't actually a bash script.

Comment: I guess the .sh threw me off then. thanks.

Comment: It's probably some kind of configuration file for an application.

Comment: The `.sh` extension usually means a shell script. Could these lines be inside a here-doc that's being passed to some other command?

Comment: The `.sh` extension gets really overused -- frankly, it shouldn't even be used for bash scripts, since (1) they aren't POSIX sh scripts (`sh` can't be used to run them if they have any bash-only syntax), and (2) extensions should be used for *libraries*, not *executables*. (That's why you have files named ending in `.py` in `/usr/lib/python`, but actual executables in `/usr/bin` don't have a `.py` on the end, even if they use Python as their interpreter).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy While it's true that `.sh` extension is overused, it would be really perverse to use it on something that isn't a shell script at all. I suspect this is data in the script, not actual shell commands.

Comment: it's a script that is suppose to send commands to a piece of hardware. the values don't actually have spaces before/after, that was a copying mistake by me when i typed it out.

Comment: @blindside044, ...can you copy-and-paste the *exact* content? The single-quotes in the last line make it not make much sense, but I'm wondering if perhaps they aren't literal (or are another copy/paste error).

Comment: If you're sure it's supposed to be a shell script, copy'n'paste more of it into the question.  As it stands, your code is not credible.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and do so.  It doesn't have to be the complete script; it has to be enough for us to be able to see that it is shell and diagnose the problems.

Comment: @blindside044, ...btw, part of what makes this question a, err, *questionable* one is that we don't know what the "this syntax" you're asking about is.

Comment: my apologies, i didn't want to post anything i shouldn't be so I tried to make it vague. i've edited the question to show the full line. sorry for the confusion. I'm curious what that last part does.

Comment: In that context, `'=value9 $S_ID $VALUE1 $VALUE2'` is passed to the program being run *exactly* as given. None of the values are replaced with variables -- it's literally a string that starts with `=value9` and ends with `$VALUE2`.

Comment: ...so, determining the meaning of that string starting with `=value` and ending with `$VALUE2` is more a question about usage of `custom_cmd`

Comment: okay, thank you, so it doesn't modify any values then. that was what I was looking for. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content within single quotes is literal -- it's not modified by the shell in any way before invoking the program that's being run.

Thus, `=value9 $S_ID $VALUE1 $VALUE2` is passed to the command being run *exactly as-is* (without `$VALUE1` being replaced with `123` and without `$VALUE2` being replaced with `456`); its meaning, then, depends on how that command interprets it.

Answer (score 0):

'  '     - supress all expansions
"  "   - supress all expansion, but parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. Basically $ ` \  are expanded in double quotes and also ! If history is enabled. @ * has also special meaning when in double quotes (check parameter expansion for more details).